# How do i prove that $Res(f(z)e^\frac{1}{z};0)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a_n}{(n+1)!}$ with $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, residue-calculus

$f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n$  (around $0$)

I need to prove that $Res(f(z)e^\frac{1}{z};0)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a_n}{(n+1)!}$

I know that $Res(z^ne^\frac{1}{z},0)=\frac{1}{(n+1)!}$

but I don't know how to procede next...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost done, since $Res (z^ne^\frac{1}{z},0)=\frac{1}{(n+1)!}$, you have $Res(a_nz^ne^\frac{1}{z},0)=a_nRes (z^ne^\frac{1}{z},0)=\frac{a_n}{(n+1)!}$, by linearity of the residues.

Also by linearity you have : $Res(\sum_{n=0}^k a_nz^n,0)=\sum_{n=0}^ka_nRes(z^ne^\frac{1}{z},0)=\sum_{n=0}^k\frac{a_n}{(n+1)!}$.

$\sum_{n=0}^k\frac{a_n}{(n+1)!}$ is convergent, so we can make $k$ tends to $\infty$. So $Res(f(z)e^\frac{1}{z};0)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a_n}{(n+1)!}$.